# Excel-VBA User form text entry

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I am trying to make a userform for users to entry a text ,which will set as a worksheet name. Because worksheet names cannot be longer than 30 characters, I want to add a warning. But in the macro, it gives me an error.

I am checking it with this scenario;

First I am writing a name longer then 30 chars.
It gives me the error which I wrote. ( which is great )
Then drops me to the entry screen again ( which is great )
Then I am writing the correct name ( shorter then 30 chars. )
It gives me Run-time error '1004; Application-defined or object-defined error.

The codes are like this;

```
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Show

If Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet = "" Then
    MsgBox "Lütfen Sheet adi seçiniz"
    GoTo son

ElseIf Len(Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet) > 30 Then
MsgBox "Sheet adi 30 karakterden kisa olmalidir"
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Show

Else
Yeni_Sheet = CStr(Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet.Value)
End If
```

Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet is giving me "Object variable or With block variable not set" error with F8 control. :(

I am open to any suggestions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where do you have this code? as in, is it in a trigger?

Comment: This is not triggered. When I run the whole macro, it comes after an event.  What I am trying to achieve is to copy a specified worksheet from a selected workbook ( works fine ), change the sheetname of that worksheet in the main workbook with the macro ( which I have a problem with ) and run some other macros on that worksheet ( works fine ).

Comment: Codes works great if I write a name shorter then 30 chars in the first place. But if I write a name with 35 chars and change it afterwards, it gives me the error.

Comment: is 'Yeni_Sheet' a Range? If so try to use the .Value property

Comment: No it's the text part of the userform1. Userform1 is named as "Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur" and the text area is named as "Yeni_Sheet"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I missed the part with, what happens after entering longer then 30 chars, so I added a "GoTo" code. Now it looks like this and works great;

```
Son1:
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Show

If Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet = "" Then
    MsgBox "Lütfen Sheet adi seçiniz"
    GoTo son

ElseIf Len(Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet) > 30 Then
MsgBox "Sheet adi 30 karakterden kisa olmalidir"
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Hide
GoTo Son1

Else
Yeni_Sheet = CStr(Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet.Value)
End If
```